# ROS Indigo and libav libraries' version

Tags: ros, opencv, ubuntu, ubuntu-trusty, library

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I updated my computer from Ubuntu 12.04 ROS Hydro to ubuntu 14.04 ROS Indigo.
One node is causing me problems. It is a C++ node, a kind of modification of the [face_recognition](http://wiki.ros.org/action/fullsearch/face_recognition?action=fullsearch&context=180&value=linkto%3A%22face_recognition%22) package

Now when I try to start it, my system complains that libavformat.so.53 was not found (It was complaining about libtiff4 so I somehow managed to install it manually from the binaries for ubuntu 13). I searched for it and I found it in Trash while in the /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ folder there was a newer version libavformat.so.54. I actually don't have any idea where this dependency comes from, I never added it, maybe from OpenCV?

I tried copying it manually (impossible to install libavformat 53 on 14.04) to the libs folder and my node finally worked. The problem now is that when I start the face recognition, there is no window appearing with the webcam images published to the topic I subscribe to. I just get the "Opengl support available" that one normally gets before a window is opened with OpenCv. I am suspecting this manual copy of the library to cause this weird behavior. My node worked fine on Ubuntu 12.04

I also had this same experience  in the past with other packages but under 12.04 with Hydro and Groovy, [Face Tracking](http://wiki.ros.org/pi_face_tracker) and [Camera calibration](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration) did both start but just show "Opengl support available" and stop there, no window with webcam images is shown.

I also tried to run some other packages that use images, image_view for example returns the same error (libavformat.so.53 not found) can somebody reproduce this error?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188517/ros-indigo-and-libav-libraries%27-version/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2014-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok I could solve this problem finally. libopencv-dev was causing all the troubles. Somehow libopencv-dev was installed by apt-get without caring about some missing dependencies. I deleted it, and tried to compile OpenCv by myself but got some errors about some static libraries (.a) that cannot be linked and asked me to recompile with -fPIC. So I followed this tutorial to compile OpenCV

> http://www.ozbotz.org/opencv-installation/

It worked and I have the latest stable OpenCV version now.
My face recognition is also working again like it did before on Hydro with Ubuntu 12.04.

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2014-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0